# Where are the .framework files?

Tags: file, macos

I am wondering where the `.framework` files are located. I am using Mac OS 10.6. If this is more of a Superuser question just tell me because I was having trouble determining whether to put it here or Superuser or here but it seemed like it should go here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a single place where `.framework` folders/files are, they are all over the place. Just search for ".framework" in the Finder, search in "This Mac" for "File Name" and add "System files" "are included" as criterion.

[search http://img.skitch.com/20100510-dfjnqgm71kcghudp5e5wwibupg.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20100510-dfjnqgm71kcghudp5e5wwibupg.jpg)

Comment: Ok thanks I'll vote it up when I can.